# User object not saving in afterSave code

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have tried multiple variations of this and for some reason the field "Followers" is not being incremented:

```
ParseObject follow = new ParseObject("Follow");
follow.put("from", currentUser);
follow.put("to", parseUser);
follow.put("approved", approved);
```

Then in cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Follow", function(request) {
    var to = request.object.get("to");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("objectId", to.id);
    query.first({
        success: function(user) {
            user.increment("Followers");
            user.save();
            console.log("User: " + user.id + " Followers: " + user.get("Followers"));
        }, error: function(error) {
            console.log("afterSave: " + error);
        }
    });

    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    currentUser.increment("Following");
    currentUser.save();
});
```

According to the logs it is working:

I2015-11-28T18:21:54.745Z]v47 after_save triggered for Follow for user k0ZvNAy3Mk:
  Input: {"object":{"approved":false,"createdAt":"2015-11-28T18:21:54.743Z","from":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"k0ZvNAy3Mk"},"objectId":"JQBO9m21uA","to":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"bcpbFaXj9C"},"updatedAt":"2015-11-28T18:21:54.743Z"}}
  Result: Success
I2015-11-28T18:21:54.906Z]User: bcpbFaXj9C Followers: 1

But when I look at the data the Followers field for that user still says 0

I have also tried:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Follow", function(request) {
    var to = request.object.get("to");
    to.increment("Followers");
    to.save();

    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    currentUser.increment("Following");
    currentUser.save();
});
```

According to the docs since it is a pointer I should be able to manipulate it directly but that did not work either.

Any ideas what to do or why this is not working correctly?

Comment: your code looks okay...what type is followers and following fields?

Comment: Followers and Following are both Numbers. Following on the user is working correctly, its just Followers on the other user not being incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the parse cloud code depends on the user that is currently logged in and manipulating data on another user is not allowed unless you are logged in as them.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Follow", function(request) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); // Needed this

    var to = request.object.get("to");
    to.increment("Followers");
    to.save();

    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    currentUser.increment("Following");
    currentUser.save();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

save() is asynchronous function, you should not leave the function before it is completed. Use this:

```
user.save().then(function(success){
console.log("User: " + success.id + " Followers: " + success.get("Followers"));
}, function (error){
console.log(error.message);
});
```

Comment: Got this in the log:

I2015-11-29T19:22:15.553Z]Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError

Comment: Looks like I needed to add:

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();